# TinyMCE Editor acts weird on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce

I use TinyMCE and it works fine on FireFox but it shows weird icons on IE 8.0.

[image: TinyMCE]
<sub>(source: [codepremise.com](http://images.codepremise.com/pictures/0001/0522/tinymce.png))</sub>

As you can see, forecolor and backcolor icons are repeated. This doesn't happen on FF.

Has anybody seen this? How do I fix this?

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you just need to upgrade, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367158/tinymce-double-forecolor-and-backcolor-buttons):

> Version 3.2.2 of TinyMCE includes the
>   changelog note: Fixed bug where IE 8
>   would render colorpicker/filepicker
>   icons incorrectly.